# Panel frontpage overrides site front page after migration

Tags: migrations, panels

I have migrated an old Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8.

On the old site I used a panel page as a front page.

Now on the new site there is no way to change this path.

No matter what I put in the "default front page" form on the "Basic site settings" page the front page keeps linking to the old panel node. And if I delete all panel nodes and the panel module itself I get a 404.

So I'm guessing this is some weird variable stored in the database but I have not been able to locate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by rolling back the "***_d6_i18n_system_site" 
So this seems to be some kind of hiccup between the panels and i18n migrations.